# RegEx.IgnoreCase issue

Tags: regex, vb.net, ignore-case

For example, I have a small function that returns a string in between two other strings (think in between single quotes, double quotes or even a simple html tag).

```
        Dim exp As String = String.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", beginMarker, endMarker)
```

Now, if I pass "<b>" in for the beginMarker and "</b>" in for the end marker and I don't specify RegEx.Ignore case it returns correctly for the matching lower case <b></b>.  Once I specify IgnoreCase however, it never returns (assuming the same input).  Here's an example function (remove RegexOptions.IgnoreCase and it works).  Also, whether I escape the markers being inputed it doesn't seem to change the output, the only difference is the IgnoreCase:

My question is, what am I missing (I used a simple example because I'm not actually parsing HTML with attributes)?

Input:  beginMarker = "<b>"
Input:  endMarker = "</b>"
Input:  searchText = "<b>this is a test</b>"
Input:  beginMakers (doesn't matter, True or False)

```
Public Shared Function GetStringInBetween(beginMarker As String, endMarker As String, searchText As String, includeMarkers As Boolean) As List(Of String)
    beginMarker = RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(beginMarker)
    endMarker = RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(endMarker)
    Dim exp As String = String.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", beginMarker, endMarker)
    Dim regEx As New RegularExpressions.Regex(exp)
    Dim returnList As New List(Of String)

    For Each m As Match In regEx.Matches(searchText, 0, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
        If includeMarkers = True Then
            returnList.Add(m.Value)
        Else
            returnList.Add(m.Value.TrimStart(beginMarker.ToCharArray).TrimEnd(endMarker.ToCharArray))
        End If
    Next

    Return returnList
End Function
```

Comment: It is impossible to reliably parse HTML tags with a regex.  Make sure you are not depending on this behavior, or find another way to do it.

Comment: I just used the bold tag for an example.  Just think two static markers like a single quote.  'this is a test' or 'This Is A Test'.  I assumed that the IgnoreCase would allow both of these to be matched but when I toggled it on, neither are matched.

Comment: Are you using matches right?  and consider the following situation: `<b><b></b>Something</b>`

Comment: I didn't, but that is a good example to prove your point.  I'm really interested in quotes and double quotes (where '''Something' would return a blank and then 'Something', e.g. 2 matches).  My question still lays in, why does the above VB/RegEx code work when IgnoreCase is left off.. but now when it's toggled on).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't use a .NET class name for the name of a variable as things could get confusing.

This works, and I changed out the Trim functions so that case is ignored:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

    Public Function GetStringInBetween(beginMarker As String, endMarker As String, searchText As String, includeMarkers As Boolean) As List(Of String)
        Dim exp As String = String.Format("{0}(.*?){1}", Regex.Escape(beginMarker), Regex.Escape(endMarker))
        Dim returnList As New List(Of String)

        For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(searchText, exp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
            If includeMarkers Then
                returnList.Add(m.Value)
            Else
                ' return the portion of the matched string without the markers
                returnList.Add(m.Value.Substring(beginMarker.Length, m.Value.Length - beginMarker.Length - endMarker.Length))
            End If
        Next

        Return returnList

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        ' include a \ to confirm the regex escaping 
        ' outputs: "hello, again"
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", GetStringInBetween("<x>", "</\x>", "<X>hello</\x> world <x>again</\x>", False).ToArray))
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Edit: Oh yeah, use **Option Strict On** too. And there is no overload of RegEx.Matches that takes (String, Int32, String) as parameters.

Comment: Perfect.. that exactly answers the behavior I was seeing (which was my fault, I didn't have option strict on and it appears was mixing and matching overloads).